# Issue with Mousemove in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having an issue with the mousemove function in a three.js scene. The goal is for the text to change color when the mouse is over the object. I've followed many [examples](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Mouse-Over.html) from the web and the raycaster doesn't register the object. I tried adding update() in the function animate() like in the link above, but the console indicates an error, "update is not defined." I can't put the mousemove function after the init function because it doesn't recognize the object variable.

```
var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }, INTERSECTED;
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
var scene, camera,renderer; 

function init(font){...
//loaded the font, camera, etc.

var option="object";
var geometry_option= new THREE.TextGeometry( option{font:font, size:200,height:20,  curveSegments:2});
var material_option = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000000, side: THREE.BackSide } );
var option1= new THREE.Mesh(geometry_option, material_option); //added the position and added it to the scene.

//added other functions under function init such as mousedown,mousemove, etc.


document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
function update()
{
   // find intersections
   // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
   //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
   var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
   projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
   var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

   // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
   var intersects_option= ray.intersectObjects([option1] );

   if ( intersects_option.length > 0 )
   {
      if ( intersects_option[ 0 ].object != INTERSECTED )
      {
         if ( INTERSECTED )
            INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
         INTERSECTED = intersects_option[ 0 ].object;

         INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();

         INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 );
      }
   }
   else 
   {
       if ( INTERSECTED )
           INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
       INTERSECTED = null;
   }
}

} // close init function
```

Comment: issue with => bad title.

Comment: Give me a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) so I can fix it. It looks like a n00b question. I can help. Or create the `.html` file containing the problem and give me a web address so I can test. I can't run code now.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent Yes, the title is awful, but I don't know why it's not working. The console doesn't show an error message. It doesn't work on jsfiddle and I can't give you the .html file.

Comment: Let's [go into the JavaScript room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) to discuss about the question. We are happy to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m4392qq2/ Our progress making the test case. The text geometry works just like everything else, so we changed it to green cube.

Comment: RE: jsfiddle.net/m4392qq2 -- it needs to be ...object.material.color.setHex(...) rather than material.setHex(...)